# Where can I see my visits in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics seems to have changed overnight and I can't see visit counts. I can see pageviews, but not visits. Any ideas?

Comment: Your personal visits? People who visit the site you can see from audience - overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in left sidebar for Audience > Overview.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Visits is now showing up under Overview, but it was not showing up as an option the other day. I'm absolutely not making this up. This kind of thing has happened to me with GA before--some option from a menu disappears for a period of time.

Comment: Have you tried to click in "**Audience**"? The _Overview_ option shows right below of Audience, when Audience is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing traffic go to audience -> overview
For view all sources go to traffic  sources -> All traffic

Make sure you are viewing under standard report which is a default reporting system.